# MySQL comparing Japanese characters in a query as question marks

Tags: c#, mysql, character-encoding, localization

I have a MySQL database with some varchar fields that can contain Latin characters or Japanese characters. There are entries that contain Japanese characters, that is not a problem. However, from my C# code, using `MySqlConnection`, I have been unable to get the correct results using Japanese characters in my `WHERE` clauses. It seems to compare the Japanese characters as though they are question marks. For example a query with `WHERE series_title LIKE '%未来警%'` does not return values where `series_title` contains "未来警", but instead returns all entries where `series_title` contains "???".

Some details:

- `series_title` is a `varchar(150)` with collation `utf8_general_ci`.
- the `ConnectionString` for the `MySqlConnection` includes the kv pair `CharSet=utf8_general_ci`
- the database does contain Japanese characters and is able to return them to the C# client - it only has problems when Japanese characters are being sent to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `charset=utf8` to your connection string:

`server=server;uid=my_user;password=pass;database=db;charset=utf8;`

EDIT:

Try execute this sql after connect:

`SET NAMES utf8`

Comment: I have tried it with `charset=utf8`, as well as with `charset=utf8_general_ci`, as well as with no charset listed at all. The problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure your data is stored using the [right encoding](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html). For Japanese, you might want to try eucjp, and you can find out [more than you ever wanted to know about character encoding here](http://www.bluebox.net/about/blog/2009/07/mysql_encoding/). It looks like you [may also need the BOM](http://www.webmasterworld.com/webmaster/4168927.htm). Best of luck and let me know how you get on.